# Raspberry PI4 slow ethernet

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-4

I have some issue with my LAN network with Rasberry PI 4.
My network in PI has configuration:

```
eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
```

when I run iper3 on PI:

```
iperf3 -s
```

a then on PC as client:

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.1.5
```

then I have result:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  8.54 MBytes  7.16 Mbits/sec    0  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  8.49 MBytes  7.12 Mbits/sec       receiver
```

which is very bad. Can you help me please?

Thank you

Comment: well, we all know what a raspberry pi 4 is ... but `then on PC as client` ... tell us a little more about this "pc"

Comment: I have two laptot with the same result. First has Windows OS and the second has Linux/Debian OS. The test was from wifi connection, but from wired it's similar.

Comment: so, what is the speed between the two laptops?

Comment: What other devices (router/switches/wifi) are between the connection from the PC to the RasPi? How do you verified that's a problem of the RasPi?